# Completion of a metric space in categorical terms

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, category-theory

Is it possible to define the completion of a metric space using categorical terms?

Comment: If you want to work in the category of metric spaces with morphisms continuous functions, I don't think this is possible. You would want the construction to be functorial but the maps that blow up at missing points can't be extended to maps of the completed spaces.

Comment: Can you clarify if by "define" you mean "characterise" or "construct"? (I'd like to know whether I misunderstood and hence should delete my answer.)

Comment: @DanielFischer: I mean *definition*, that determine completion up to isomorphism. Not matter, with constructive way or not. Don't delete your answer, please; I like it.

Comment: The universal property of the completion "defines"/characterizes it uniquely up to isometry.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The completion of a metric space $X$ is an initial object in the category $\mathcal{U}_X$ whose objects are uniformly continuous maps $\iota_Y \colon X \to Y$, where $Y$ is a complete metric space, and whose morphisms are uniformly continuous maps $f \colon Y \to Z$ such that $f \circ \iota_Y = \iota_Z$.

Comment: We wanted to define complete metric space. You assume its defined a merely build on that. -1

Comment: @Marek I understood "define" as "characterise" here. If it was meant as "construct", that would of course be an entirely different beast, and I'd have no idea whether that'd be possible. Thanks for explaining the downvote, much appreciated.

Comment: Also, I think we should stay in a category of metric spaces with suitable notion of morphism. Otherwise the definition is not very useful.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Can you recommend books when I can read about such a definition?

Comment: @user14284 Terribly sorry, but no. I hardly know any category theory, can't name any books that might include something like that.

Comment: @user14284 Almost the same definitins, theorems and explanations are given for the case of Normed spaces in the book Lectures And Exercises on Functional Analysis (Translations of Mathematical Monographs) by A. Ya. Helemskii

Answer (score 2):

At least for Lawvere metric spaces it is a special case of the [Cauchy completion](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Cauchy+complete+category).